# Command prompt not executing powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, powershell-4.0

I tried running a build today and found that my command prompt is not able to execute powershell scripts. To confirm this, I created a test powershell script which simply writes to console. The script works fine when run from powershell, but is not recognizable by the command prompt. Screenshots below.

[test script working from powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFuz2.jpg)

[test script not working from command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOrrm.jpg)

Any suggestions/explantion as to why this is happening?

Comment: PowerShell does not use the current working directory as a default location to search for executables. Use `powershell -NoProfile -File .\test1.ps1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works perfectly. But my powershell scripts were working fine from command prompt earlier without the "-NoProfile" switch parameter. I don't remember making any changes to the command prompt settings

Comment: You do not have to use `-NoProfile`. Try it without `-NoProfile`. But, if any of your profile scripts ever writes output, it will appear in your script output. Try it without `-File` as well. It will work. But, it depends on the parameter being at position 0.

Comment: I am executing the script as `powershell .\test1.ps1` without any switch parameters. This is not working. I tried it with `-NoProfile`, which works.

Comment: Resolved it. I created a `profile.ps1` script under `..\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` folder to load custom settings for powershell. Removing `profile.ps1` from the folder or adding a `-NoProfile` switch parameter solves this. @lit - Thanks for your input. Helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. I created a `profile.ps1` script under `..\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` folder to load custom settings for powershell. Removing `profile.ps1` from the folder or adding a `-NoProfile` switch parameter solves this.